# pandas: Better way to update and merge dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge, updates

Consider the two dataframes `df_a` and `df_b`:

```
>>> df_a = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({1: [1,2,3], 2: ["a", "b", "c"], 3:[4,5,6]})
>>> df_a.index = pd.Index([0,1,3])
>>> print(df_a)

   1  2  3
0  1  a  4
1  2  b  5
3  3  c  6

>>> df_b = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({2: ["d", "e", "f", "g"]})
>>> print(df_b)

   2
0  d
1  e
2  f
3  g
```

And the following code:

```
>>> df_a = pd.concat([df_a, df_b])
>>> df_c = df_a.loc[~df_a.index.duplicated(keep='last'),df_b.columns]
>>> df_d = df_a.loc[~df_a.index.duplicated(keep='first'), ~df_a.columns.isin(df_b.columns)]
>>> df_e = df_d.merge(df_c, "outer", left_index=True, right_index=True)
>>> df_e.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Which produces the desired dataframe (`df_e`):

```
>>> print(df_e)
     1  2    3
0  1.0  d  4.0
1  2.0  e  5.0
2  NaN  f  NaN
3  3.0  g  6.0
```

Is there a more efficient way to get to `df_e`? I have tried various methods of using `pd.concat`, `pd.merge` and `pd.update`, but my efforts have resulted in one or more of these undesirable consequences:

1. It disrupts the index of `df_a` (i.e. the values do not have the same index - some sort of index creation happens 'under the hood').
2. Columns get renamed.
3. NaNs appear in places where `df_a` values should be.

Basically, the operation I want to perform is:

1. Update `df_a` with values of `df_b`.
2. If values exist in `df_b` that do not have corresponding index/columns, expand `df_a` appropriately to include these values (keeping the index/columns in the appropriate order).

EDIT: Provided better example that isn't naturally sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two straightforward-ish ways to obtain your `df_e`; I'm not going to think much about column order, though. Adding an extra column 4 to `df_b`, just to show the behaviour for columns not present in `df_a`:

```
In [63]: m = df_b.combine_first(df_a)

In [64]: m
Out[64]: 
     1  2    3   4
0  1.0  d  4.0  10
1  2.0  e  5.0  11
2  NaN  f  NaN  12
3  3.0  g  6.0  13
```

or

```
In [65]: a,b = df_a.align(df_b)

In [66]: a.update(b)

In [67]: a
Out[67]: 
     1  2    3     4
0  1.0  d  4.0  10.0
1  2.0  e  5.0  11.0
2  NaN  f  NaN  12.0
3  3.0  g  6.0  13.0
```

Note the slight difference in dtype introduced by the alignment.

Comment: Could you please explain what was the problem you were solving by the ``align`` and then ``update`` operations? It looks to me as if you solved the problem just with ``combine_first``... Was that in response to my comment about ordering the index/columns...?

Answer (score 2):

Reading through pandas [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and blogs [here](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_join_merge_dataframe/) and [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) should help you.

From the blogs:

> “Left outer join produces a complete set of records from Table A, with the matching records (where available) in Table B. If there is no match, the right side will contain null.”

```
df_b.join(df_a, how='left', lsuffix='_b').drop('2', axis=1).rename(columns={'2_b': 2})

    2   1   3
0   d   1.0 4.0
1   e   2.0 5.0
2   f   NaN NaN
3   g   3.0 6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
df_b[[1, 3]] = df_a[[1, 3]]
```

Result:

```
print(df_b)

   2    1    3
0  d  1.0  4.0
1  e  2.0  5.0
2  f  NaN  NaN
3  g  3.0  6.0
```

Comment: This answer relies on knowing the affected columns, and I don't think it would produce the right answer if the ``index`` of ``df_b`` was shorter than ``df_a``. My use case is that it is not guaranteed that the index/columns of ``df_a`` or ``df_b`` is a superset/subset of the respective index/columns of the other.

Comment: @Charlie, Of course, that is true. It wasn't clear to me from your question what the restrictions were. I'll leave this here, nevertheless, for others who happen to know column names in advance.